# how can I express enforcement in past tense

Tags: grammar, past-tense

How can I express enforcement in the past,please looking at below sentence

present  : He has to wait for a long time.
past :He had to wait for a long time (it's not past perfect i want to mention an enforcement in the past)

Is second sentence true?

Comment: It is if he had to wait.

Comment: Note that we say a sentence is *true* or *false* depending on the real-life facts that it expresses. You may mean "Is the second sentence [grammatically] correct/incorrect?"

Answer (score 2):

> He has to wait.

is present tense.  He must wait now.

> He had to wait [yesterday].

is past tense.  He was forced to wait at some point in the past, perhaps yesterday.

> He has had to wait [three times this week].

is present perfect.  He was forced to wait at some indeterminate times in the past, which times could extend all the way up to the present.

> [Before they built the new bridge] he had had to wait [for up to three
>   hours to cross the river].

is past perfect.  His waiting took place in the past but before a specified time also in the past, like the building of a new bridge.

> He will have to wait [until I get back].

is future.  His waiting extends beyond now, perhaps because I haven't returned.

> He will have waited three hours by the time I get back.

is future perfect.  It contemplates completed action in the future.  I haven't returned yet but when I do, three hours of waiting will be over.

Comment: Precise, concise and lucid. Nailed it.